# wrong encoding csv file generated by a py2exe script

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, character-encoding, py2exe

I've programmed a script in Python 3 that generates a CSV file and it works fine running the .py file from console or Pycharm IDE.  The encoding of the output file is correct. My locale settings are:

```
>>> locale.getpreferredencoding()
'cp1252'
```

Then I've packed it in an executable file with Py2exe in Win 7.  It works, but the output CSV file has an incorrect encoding, it's encoded with UTF-8, and characters like `á é í ó ú ñ` doesn't display correctly in Excel.

The code

```
with open('temp_gesfincas.csv', newline='') as infh, \
        open('output_gesfincas.csv', 'w', encoding='cp1252', newline='') as outfh:
    reader = csv.reader(infh, delimiter=';')
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfh, fields, dialect='spanish')
    writer.writeheader()
    row = {}
    for linea in reader:
        print(linea)
        key = linea[0]
        try:    
            value = linea[1]
        except IndexError:
            value = ''
            continue
        if key in row:
            writer.writerow(row)
            row = {}
        row[key] = value
    if row:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Have you checked the file with Notepad++? Maybe the reason why you can' t find these characters is the Excel' s mistake? I' ve run into this situation before. Check the bytes in the file with Notepad++' s hex plugin.

Comment: Can you show us the actual code please? How are you opening the file? `open()` uses the *system default encoding* unless you specify a different codec. Can you also show the actual output produced in the file (preferably by opening it as binary, then showing us the `repr()` of the offending lines).

Comment: `"spanish"` is not a valid argument for `dialect`.

Comment: @Alpay yes I've checked the file with Notepad++.  The output of Hex plugin for the word 'Código' is: `43 c3 b3 64 69 67 6f`.  @MartijnPieters the output of showing the repr() opened as binary: `b'C\xc3\xb3digo;Nombre;Direcci\xc3\xb3n;Poblaci\xc3\xb3n'`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Yes, but I've registered: `csv.register_dialect('spanish', delimiter=';')` in order to use DictWriter with ';' delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved !

First at all, I set de encoding of the script to `# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-`.  The generated characters changed, but were wrong too.

Since I've read this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pythonhispano/gV3kvSJY75k I've changed the special comment line:

```
 # -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
```

By this other line:

```
# -*- coding: 850 -*-
```

Why?  Answering myself:

While Windows uses cp1252 encoding, as seen with:

```
>>> locale.getpreferredencoding()
'cp1252'
```

The console of windows `cmd` uses cp850, as you can see with:

```
C:\Users\Trimax\Dev\Tests>chcp
Active code page: 850
```

Well, in the setup.py script that must be used to 'compile' you can set the console or the windows parameter with the file name of your script, depending on what you what (console program or GUI program).  If 'console' is asigned in the setup.py file the encoding used is 850 so you must set the encodig of the script to `# -*- coding: 850 -*-`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which encodings `py2exe` supports, but for proper support of unicode characters the encodings package needs to be included in the `.exe`.

To include this add the option `--packages encodings`.

Comment: By default py2exe includes all the encoding packages, in fact, there is the /encodings/cp1251.pyc in the library packed with de .exe, and all the other encodings files .pyc.  I suspect that it concerns to an issue of access to the locale settings.

Comment: Yeah, I see that this is no longer needed. I found this post that might be interesting http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/EvenMoreEncodings?

Comment: I tried the solution given by py2exe.org/index.cgi/EvenMoreEncodings? but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Maybe it is worth trying a different encoding?